# Monotouch error: mtouch exited with code 1

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have a huge problem.
I am a new customer in the ios applications world, and I'm trying to work with Xamarin Studio.
This is the output error after starting the debug on my ios device: iphone ios 7.0.4.
Monotouch 5.0.1 and Xamarin version 4.0.5
Someone can help me?!
The ios simulator run correctly (debug and release mode), but i can't deploy the app on my iphone.

Here the build output using iPhone Simulator 7.0.
Trying to solve the issue by myself I have made the situation worse and now I can't debug also with the simulator.

```
Performing main compilation...
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs /noconfig "/out:/Users/Blumotix/Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/HelloWorld.exe" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" /nologo /warn:4 /debug:full /optimize- /codepage:utf8 "/define:DEBUG;__MOBILE__;__IOS__"  /t:exe "/Users/Blumotix/Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/Main.cs" "/Users/Blumotix/Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/AppDelegate.cs" "/Users/Blumotix/Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/HelloWorldViewController.cs" "/Users/Blumotix/Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/HelloWorldViewController.designer.cs" 
Generazione completata -- 0 errori, 0 avvisi

Compiling to native code
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -v --nomanifest --nosign -sim "/Users/Blumotix/Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/HelloWorld.app" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" -debug -nolink -sdk "7.0" "/Users/Blumotix/Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/HelloWorld.exe"
Framework does not exist /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk
   Platform = iPhoneSimulator
   SDK = 7.0
   Deployment Version: 3.0
Framework is: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/SDKSettings.plist".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity (System.Uri absoluteUri, System.String role, System.Type ofObjectToReturn) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.GetStreamFromUrl (System.String url, System.String& absoluteUriString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadTextReader (Int32 remained) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.PeekChar () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadContent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml.EntityResolvingXmlReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml.DTDValidatingReader.ReadContent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml.DTDValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml.Schema.XsdValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNodeCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNode (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.String filename) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MTouch.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/SDKSettings.plist".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity (System.Uri absoluteUri, System.String role, System.Type ofObjectToReturn) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.GetStreamFromUrl (System.String url, System.String& absoluteUriString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadTextReader (Int32 remained) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.PeekChar () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadContent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml.EntityResolvingXmlReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml.DTDValidatingReader.ReadContent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml.DTDValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xml.Schema.XsdValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNodeCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNode (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.String filename) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MTouch.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
mtouch exited with code 1
```

Thanks.
E.

Comment: Please provide the full build output (click *Build Output* in the errors pad to see it).

Comment: I've edited the question with the error output. Hope it will be fine: I've less than 10 points so I can't answer at my question for 8 hours.  Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Xcode do you have installed and where is it installed?

Comment: Version 5.0.2 and it is installed in /Applications

Answer (score 1):

That's because MonoTouch 5.0.1 is way too old - it was released more than 2 years ago.

Since it was released Apple changed the format of some of it's `.plist` files: from XML to a binary format.

You need to update to a more recent version of Xamarin.iOS (new name for MonoTouch) that will process those files as binary. Since you're using the latest Xcode I suggest you to use the latest Xamarin.iOS version (current 7.0.x).

Comment: Thanks poupou. So hypothetically if I downgrade Xcode to the previously version (the 4th series) I can debug my app using Monotouch 5.0.1, is it correct?? And secondly, is Monotouch 5.0.1 suitable for debugging iOS7 device??

Comment: **(a)** Using an old Xcode would work (as long as your OS support that old version) but I do not recall which Xcode version changed this (but you can look in Xamarin.iOS release notes to find this). **(b)** Debugging *should* work but it's not a version mix that I ever tried myself so YMMV.